# How hide UIAlertControllers globally in the app when app enters in backround

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, uialertcontroller

I need a system to hide all `UIAlertController` in my app when she enters in background. Currently I use a `BaseViewController` class for all my `UIViewControllers` that register to "enter background" notification and has a reference to a `UIAlertViewController`. This `BaseViewController` hides the popup if it appears visible. It works but it is not practical.

An other way is subclassing but Apple doc say :

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

Do you have a better solution that does not involve subclassing the `UIViewController` who contains the `UIAlertController`  ?

Comment: What do you mean "all" `UIAlertController`? Are you displaying multiple at a time?

Comment: I have a pin code system on my app, if a popup shows when user quit the app, when the app enter on foreground, the popup is always visible. I want  that all popups in all view controllers have a dismiss behaviour when the app enter in background (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @Anthony is my answer not work for you ?

Comment: @balkaran singh Is perfect ! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plz use this code you need to get top view controller

use this method to get top view controller

```
- (id)getTopViewController {

    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }
    if (![topController isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        return topController;
    }
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UIViewController *viewOb = [self getTopViewController];

    // check  UIViewController is  UIAlertController
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",view);
        [viewOb dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

then dismissViewController with top viewController